# Refactoring many prints statements with specific conditions

Tags: python, template

How should I refactor the following Python 3.8 snippet?

```py
import enum
import typing

class Number(enum.Enum):
    one = 1
    two = 2
    three = 3
    four = 4
    five = 5
    six = 6

class Color(enum.Enum):
    white = 1
    black = 2

class Animal(enum.Enum):
    cat = 1
    dog = 2

class Toy(enum.Enum):
    ball = 1
    leash = 2

amounts: typing.Dict[typing.Tuple[Color, Number, typing.Optional[object]], int] = {
    (Color.white, Number.one, Animal.cat): 1,
    (Color.white, Number.one, Animal.dog): 2,
    (Color.white, Number.two, Animal.cat): 4,
    (Color.white, Number.two, Animal.dog): 5,
    (Color.white, Number.three, Toy.ball): 6,
    (Color.white, Number.three, Toy.leash): 7,
    (Color.white, Number.four, Toy.ball): 8,
    (Color.white, Number.four, Toy.leash): 10,
    (Color.white, Number.five, None): 11,
    (Color.white, Number.six, None): 14,
    (Color.black, Number.one, Animal.cat): 15,
    (Color.black, Number.one, Animal.dog): 16,
    (Color.black, Number.two, Animal.cat): 17,
    (Color.black, Number.two, Animal.dog): 19,
}

print(f'I. White Animals: {sum(value for (color, _, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white)}')
print(f'1. Numbers One and Two: {sum(value for (color, number, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number in (Number.one, Number.two))}')
print(f'1.1. Number One: {sum(value for (color, number, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.one)}')
print(f'     First White Cats: {sum(value for (color, number, animal), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.one and animal == Animal.cat)}')
print(f'     First White Dogs: {sum(value for (color, number, animal), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.one and animal == Animal.dog)}')
print(f'1.2. Number Two: {sum(value for (color, number, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.two)}')
print(f'     Second White Cats: {sum(value for (color, number, animal), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.two and animal == Animal.cat)}')
print(f'     Second White Dogs: {sum(value for (color, number, animal), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.two and animal == Animal.dog)}')
print(f'2. Numbers Three and Four: {sum(value for (color, number, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number in (Number.three, Number.four))}')
print(f'2.1. Number Three: {sum(value for (color, number, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.three)}')
print(f'     Balls: {sum(value for (color, number, toy), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.three and toy == Toy.ball)}')
print(f'     Leashes: {sum(value for (color, number, toy), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.three and toy == Toy.leash)}')
print(f'2.2. Number Four: {sum(value for (color, number, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.four)}')
print(f'     Balls: {sum(value for (color, number, toy), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.four and toy == Toy.ball)}')
print(f'     Leashes: {sum(value for (color, number, toy), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.four and toy == Toy.leash)}')
print(f'3. Number Five: {sum(value for (color, number, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.five)}')
print(f'4. Number Six: {sum(value for (color, number, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.white and number == Number.six)}')
print(f'II. Black Animals: {sum(value for (color, _, _), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.black)}')
print(f'    First Black Cats: {sum(value for (color, number, animal), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.black and number == Number.one and animal == Animal.cat)}')
print(f'    First Black Dogs: {sum(value for (color, number, animal), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.black and number == Number.one and animal == Animal.dog)}')
print(f'    Second Black Cats: {sum(value for (color, number, animal), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.black and number == Number.two and animal == Animal.cat)}')
print(f'    Second Black Dogs: {sum(value for (color, number, animal), value in amounts.items() if color == Color.black and number == Number.two and animal == Animal.dog)}')
```

Although the context of the code was changed (it's not about cats and dogs), the code must have these 22 `print` statements and must filter `amounts` using each shown condition on its respective `print` statement.

Note that sections `I.` and `II.` filter animals based on their color, sections `1.`, `2.`, `3.`, `4.` filter animals based on their number, and the remaining sections have some specific filters depending on its parent section.

I don't know how a for-loop could solve that.

Comment: This is borderline on-topic/off-topic. Code Review considers context fairly important, so a case could be made for closure under _Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site._ Here I'll still answer.

Comment: @Reinderien Sorry about that. I thought that, since the main part of the code review for this specific question is about removing duplicates of a given working code snippet, the context was not *that* necessary and could be changed without prejudice (especially because the code is a bit larger than the shown snippet). Please let me know if it makes a difference so I can update the post with the true context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically the members of enum classes should be capitalised since they're constants.

Run a PEP8 linter on this code. Your inter-class spacing is not correct.

Don't use `object` during typing. If you truly don't know anything about a type, write `Any`.

Lots of ways to reduce the repetition in the last part of the code. Fundamentally, your selectors have an O(n^2) problem since you need to re-express the tree root every time you navigate. You could write a navigation tree structure that is traversed by a recursive function:

```py
import enum
from typing import Iterator, Sequence


class Number(enum.Enum):
    one = 1
    two = 2
    three = 3
    four = 4
    five = 5
    six = 6


class Color(enum.Enum):
    white = 1
    black = 2


class Animal(enum.Enum):
    cat = 1
    dog = 2


class Toy(enum.Enum):
    ball = 1
    leash = 2


Amounts = Sequence[
    tuple[
        tuple[
            Color,
            Number,
            None | Animal | Toy,
        ],
        int,
    ]
]

KeySet = set[Color | Number | Animal | Toy] | None

MatchTree = Sequence[  # recursive
    tuple[KeySet, Sequence | str]
]


def filter_tree(
    amounts: Amounts,
    tree: MatchTree,
) -> Iterator[tuple[str, int]]:
    for key, subtree in tree:
        sub_amounts = [
            (indices[1:], amount)
            for indices, amount in amounts
            if key is None or indices[0] in key
        ]

        if isinstance(subtree, str):
            yield subtree, sum(a for k, a in sub_amounts)
        else:
            yield from filter_tree(sub_amounts, subtree)


def print_filter(amounts: Amounts, tree: MatchTree) -> None:
    for prefix, total in filter_tree(amounts, tree):
        print(f'{prefix}: {total}')


def demo() -> None:
    amounts = {
        (Color.white, Number.one, Animal.cat): 1,
        (Color.white, Number.one, Animal.dog): 2,
        (Color.white, Number.two, Animal.cat): 4,
        (Color.white, Number.two, Animal.dog): 5,
        (Color.white, Number.three, Toy.ball): 6,
        (Color.white, Number.three, Toy.leash): 7,
        (Color.white, Number.four, Toy.ball): 8,
        (Color.white, Number.four, Toy.leash): 10,
        (Color.white, Number.five, None): 11,
        (Color.white, Number.six, None): 14,
        (Color.black, Number.one, Animal.cat): 15,
        (Color.black, Number.one, Animal.dog): 16,
        (Color.black, Number.two, Animal.cat): 17,
        (Color.black, Number.two, Animal.dog): 19,
    }
    
    tree = (
        ({Color.white}, (
            (None, 'I. White Animals'),
            ({Number.one, Number.two}, '1. Numbers One and Two'),
            ({Number.one}, (
                (None,         '1.1. Number One'),
                ({Animal.cat}, '     First White Cats'),
                ({Animal.dog}, '     First White Dogs'),
            )),
            ({Number.two}, (
                (None,         '1.2. Number Two'),
                ({Animal.cat}, '     Second White Cats'),
                ({Animal.dog}, '     Second White Dogs'),
            )),
            ({Number.three, Number.four}, '2. Numbers Three and Four'),
            ({Number.three}, (
                (None,        '2.1. Number Three'),
                ({Toy.ball},  '     Balls'),
                ({Toy.leash}, '     Leashes'),
            )),
            ({Number.four}, (
                (None,        '2.2. Number Four'),
                ({Toy.ball},  '     Balls'),
                ({Toy.leash}, '     Leashes'),
            )),
            ({Number.five}, '3. Number Five'),
            ({Number.six},  '4. Number Six'),
        )),
        ({Color.black}, (
            (None, 'II. Black Animals'),
            ({Number.one}, (
                ({Animal.cat}, '    First Black Cats'),
                ({Animal.dog}, '    First Black Dogs'),
            )),
            ({Number.two}, (
                ({Animal.cat}, '    Second Black Cats'),
                ({Animal.dog}, '    Second Black Dogs'),
            )),
        )),
    )

    print_filter(amounts.items(), tree)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

```
I. White Animals: 68
1. Numbers One and Two: 12
1.1. Number One: 3
     First White Cats: 1
     First White Dogs: 2
1.2. Number Two: 9
     Second White Cats: 4
     Second White Dogs: 5
2. Numbers Three and Four: 31
2.1. Number Three: 13
     Balls: 6
     Leashes: 7
2.2. Number Four: 18
     Balls: 8
     Leashes: 10
3. Number Five: 11
4. Number Six: 14
II. Black Animals: 67
    First Black Cats: 15
    First Black Dogs: 16
    Second Black Cats: 17
    Second Black Dogs: 19
```

Comment: The tree approach is exactly what I was looking for: a concise and scalable way to express every filter layer. I thank you and apologize for anything. I truly do.